# Error while clipping raster by mask layer

Tags: qgis-3

I am using QGIS 3.8 on Mac. When I tried to extract raster by mask layer, it gives following error and its been a while I am not able to fix this.

```
"GDAL command output:
/bin/sh: gdalwarp: command not found

Execution completed in 0.08 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': '/var/folders/bn/d_gr7r2j03x_j9gphh4ncpz80000gn/T/processing_433a42df84c4486bb4b36bc2b3753302/27fec80e7c114dcebaba61cfe351e593/OUTPUT.tif'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.<ul><li>/var/folders/bn/d_gr7r2j03x_j9gphh4ncpz80000gn/T/processing_433a42df84c4486bb4b36bc2b3753302/27fec80e7c114dcebaba61cfe351e593/OUTPUT.tif</li></ul>You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm. "
```

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that QGIS cannot find the `gdalwarp` utility, which does the extract by mask layer work. I'm speaking from Windows, so I am not sure if all applies to your Mac but what you need to do is check whether the path where gdalwarp is found is given in the environment variables of QGIS. So:

- Step 1: locate `gdalwarp` on your Mac (probably somewhere under where you have installed QGIS)
- Step 2: Add the path of this to your environment variables (which you can do under Settings -> Options -> System tab)